# Mysql extract part of a string (substr, slice ?)

Tags: mysql, substring, slice

I want to substr of slice because I have a database that contains application name and their versions.

I'd like to get every version that needs to be followed. (every last version of each branch).

Those version name could be formatted 8.XX.YY.ZZZZ. And I'd like to get every last version for the 3 first set of number.

For exemple :

- 800000018
- 800000024
- 800010000
- 800010009
- 800020001
- 800020005
- 801000004
- 801000005
- 800020006
- 800020007
- 800010010
- 800020009

I would only get :

- 801000005 (8.1.0.5)
- 800020009 (8.0.2.9)
- 800010010 (8.0.1.10)
- 800000024 (8.0.0.24)

I've been thinking of a procedure that would do something like this :

get max version (here it'd be 8.1.0.5).

Then, get max version but substract by 1 if XX > 1 (8(XX -1))
And again, get max version and substract by 1 if YY>1 (800(YY-1))
Continue until there is only the 4 last number left and the first number that aren't 0.

In SQL it'd look like that :

```
select max(version_name) from application;

while (XX >0) SET XX=XX-1;
select max(version_name) from application where version_name LIKE '8XX';

while (YY>0) SET YY=YY-1;
select max(version_name) from application where version_name LIKE '800YY';

End there and last version_name should be  = 80000ZZZZ.
```

Is there a way to substr if possible from the end of the string.

I have a filter in JS that transform it on the format that I want (VV.XX.YY.ZZZZ) if it can help :

```
 parseInt(version.slice(0, -8)), parseInt(version.substr(-8, 2)),
 parseInt(version.substr(-6, 2)), parseInt(version.slice(-4))
```

I hope it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can group by substring and get the max

```
select max(version_name)
from application
group by 
substring(version_name,1,1),
substring(version_name,2,2),
substring(version_name,4,2)
```

and order/parse it as you wish

Comment: Worked like a charm.
Would have never though of a group by, I really am impressed by the thing you can do with mysql ^^. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

My query in MYSQL

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(
        '.',
        SUBSTRING(VERSION, -9, 1),
        SUBSTRING(VERSION, -8, 2) +0,
        SUBSTRING(VERSION, -6, 2) +0,
        SUBSTRING(VERSION, -4, 4) +0
    ) AS result,
    VERSION
FROM
    `test`
```

Output:

```
result    version
--------------------
8.0.0.18  800000018
8.0.2.9   800020009
8.0.1.10  800010010
8.1.0.5   801000005
```